# Java library for Docker repository?

Tags: docker

Is there a Java library for Docker *repository*? I couldn't find any. I know there are few docker api libraries, but I am looking one for the repository.

My use case includes pushing to local repo and removing from it.

I am talking about this: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/

Comment: does this https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/dockerjava/api/DockerClient.java  not fulfill your requirement?

Comment: @AnkitKumar Docker registry, not docker itself.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are only official API and SDK for `python` and `go`.
[Develop with Docker Engine SDKs and API](https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/)

You can find other unofficial API's for Java and C, for example, but I haven't tested their efficiency.